# setTitle method of ActionBarActivity not working after app recreation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

My class extends `ActionBarActivity` from the `android.support.v7.app` package.

I witnessed the following effect:

The [setTitle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)) method works fine all the time.

But when the app was put in the background, removed from the processes (tested with developer settings -> restrict background processes) and recreated, the `Activity` is recreated fine but lost it's previous title and further calls to `setTitle()`do not have any effect and the `ActionBar` title remains the unchanged default one. 
When I close the `Activity` with the back button and reopen it, everything is back to normal.

Anyone know why `ActionBarActivity` behaves that way?

Comment: Can you post the code of the Activity that sets the title?

Comment: Have you written `setTitle()` it in `onCreateView()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `ActionBarActivity` you can use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle();
```

Check official [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#getSupportActionBar()) for more info.